# VB.Net Regex replace double quote inside of brackets

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, vb.net-2010

I have been spinning my wheels trying to figure this out. I need to replace double quotes inside a set of brackets. My example below shows single quotes but I am still having issues

This works for me -

```
Dim input As String = "This is my ['Test'] that works"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=my.*)'(?=.*that)", "?")
```

Produces this string - `This is my [?Test?] that works`.

But if I try this is appends instead of replacing the single quote -

```
Dim input As String = "This is my ['Test'] that works"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=[.*)'(?=.*])", "?")
```

Produces this which is not what I want - `This is my ['?Test'?] that works`.

As you can see the Regex.replace is appending the ? after the single quote, but I need it to replace the single quote with the ?. I am stumped.

Comment: "I am stumped" -  *So am I*.

Comment: Escape `[`. `(?<=\[.*)'(?=.*])` `.*` is too greedy and may overfire with a larger text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all single quotes inside square brackets, you need to escape the opening `[` or it will be treated as a special character (opening a character class):

```
(?<=\[[^][]*)'(?=[^][]*])
```

Also, you need to restrict the characters to be different from `[` and `]`. For that, you can use a `[^][]` negated character class (this will match any character other than `[` and `]`).

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*)%27(%3F%3D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D)&i=This%20is%20my%20%5B%27Test%27%5D%20that%20works&r=%3F)

[image]

Comment: So I added an escape character like stribizhev suggested and that fixed my issue.                                                                                                                     Dim input As String = "This is my ['Test'] that works"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=\[.*)'(?=.*])", "?") but now I realized I have a larger problem. I could possibly have two sets of brackets. So my string is - MyObject:"["A","B"]","MyObject2":"["C"]" so I need to remove the double quotes inside the brackets only. So it would look like MyObject:"[A,B]","MyObject2":[C]"

Comment: Look [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*)%22(%3f%3d%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d)&i=MyObject%3a%22%5b%22A%22%2c%22B%22%5d%22%2c%22MyObject2%22%3a%22%5b%22C%22%5d%22&r=), only the double quotes inside square brackets are removed.